# Multiple API call in Single Grid

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I am binding data to Kendo grid and have following Schema.

```
     $("#divShowReports").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: data,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            ReportID: { type: "string" },
                            ReportName: { type: "string" },
                            ReportQuery: { type: "string" },
                            IsAccessToAll: { type: "string" },
                            CustomerID: { type: "string" },
                            CustUserID: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10,
            },
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            columnMenu: true,
            pageable: true,
            columns: [{
                field: "ReportName", title: "Report Name",
                template: "<a value='#=ReportQuery#' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=ShowAdhocGrid(this)>#=ReportName#</a>"
            },
                { field: "ReportID", title: "ReportID", hidden: true },
                { field: "ReportQuery", title: "Report Query" },
                { field: "IsAccessToAll", title: "Is Access to All" },
                { field: "CustUserID", title: "CustUserID" },
                { field: "CustomerID", title: "CustomerID" },

            ]
        });
    }

}
```

Now I am getting "ReportQuery" field value from different API Call. Please help me that without disturbing other things how can I merge new data into old Schema.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you set the data yourself on the grid in the data property, right?

Assuming you have several api calls, add some promises and keep track when all calls finish so you have all responses ready.

Then, do whatever you need to do, merge the datasets, update certain fields on the object you set as your dataset and you don't need to disturb anything. You control the name of the fields and what data goes into them.

all your work gets done on the datasource object basically.

Comment: "you set the data yourself on the grid in the data property, right?" NOPE..

Thats the prob... I got impaired project to work on..

Comment: that doesn't make any sense, the data must be coming from somewhere and must be assigned somehow. If my understanding is not correct can you please clarify how that happens?